# Non-lethal Cicada Repellent?

Tags: bugs

Are there any specific things (plants, specific essential oils, etc.) that repel (momentarily, not looking for a permanent 'go away and never come back' solution) cicadas in a non-lethal, preferably all natural manner?

To clarify, I'm talking about selective physical repellent - the noise cicadas make isn't an issue, I'm actually looking to protect the cicadas from, for example, landing on/too close to an individual who may react poorly to them (e.g by picking it up and throwing it across the yard). I would prefer to avoid netting and similar physical barriers, both for practical reasons, and for the fact they would tend to be out of place in an otherwise comfortable natural setting.

Temporary solutions preferred, as I personally love cicadas, and would be using such a solution for the benefit of others.

Comment: Welcome to Gardening SE! Don't forget to take the [tour] and to browse our [help] to learn more about the site! Is there a specific reason you want to repel them, e.g. the noise?

Comment: @Stephie - thanks for the prompt welcome! _I_ love cicadas...I'm actually asking for the benefit of certain others who aren't so fond of them being in close physical proximity (the kind that would scream and flail if one were to land on them) - so I'm wondering about temporary solutions to keep the cicadas physically away from those specific people, or the area they may be standing/sitting, without any risk to the cicadas themselves. To clarify: noise isn't a concern, just the physical manifestation.

Comment: Just to add to this - I'd prefer not to use netting/an actual physical barrier, since it would be impractical for the circumstances, and I would prefer something that blends better with an otherwise nature-loving environment.

Comment: Power tools attract cicadas so you could run a lawn mower to attract them away from your site.

Comment: What a cool creature.  I had no idea!  Do you know which cicada you entertain?  The annual or the 13 year or the 17 year variety?  They happen so seldom except for the annual ones I guess.  Only operate power tools at night.  I know hornets that are attracted by power tools and I had to learn to deal with those.  We humans need to understand these dudes were here way before we came onto the scene.  I couldn't find anything that made sense except a biodome?  grins.  A greenhouse over your entire home and landscape?  Seriously, they do that.  Your I - THOU attitude makes sense, good for you.